# Google Calendar Style Color Picker Android

Tags: android, colors, color-picker

I am looking to incorporate a color picker into my android app.  I would like it to look like the google calendar / today calendar picker.  I found this page which talks about add the color picker to your project but it doesn't really explain how to add it.

http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/08/color-pickers-from-google.html

Does anyone know how to incorporate this color picker into an android studio project / know of another library that provides a similar looking color chooser.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: you import it the same way you would any other library

Comment: It isn't a gradle project so I don't know how to  incorporate into my build.gradle script.  If you know how please let me know.  I tried added the extracted library folder to my app under root/libraries and then in my build.gradle compile :libraries:colorpicker but it always says it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is

- first download original Google code for colorpicker from this link
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker/

  You should Clone/Download the code to your desktop some how
- then  in android studio click the file menu and import module
- after importing the google code you have the color picker at your disposal. you may need to download the android 15 SDK for the code to run properly.
- after that you add this line to your dependencies in your build.gradle file
  compile project(':YOURMODULENAME')

  from now on you can use google's colorPicker Classes in your activites
- now you use the main activity sample from the Github page you linked in your question and use the colorPickerDialog